# Summing Records in 2 MySQL fields From Same Table and Use It As a Condition

Tags: mysql

I am working on a project, and part of it requires me to be able to display records of individuals who have completed repayment. To complete repayment they must have made monthly repayments and a lump sum. So I want to be able to sum the records in an individual's repayment amount field and lumpsum field, indentified by his loanid. Here is the sample table

Repayment table

```
loanid  |  repayment_amount  | lumpsum  | memberid
  21             20,000           30,000      45
```

loan table

```
loanid  |  amountdue  | memberid
  21        40,000         45
```

Member table

```
memberid  |  first_name  | middle_name  | last_name
  21             John        Tom            Bun
```

Here is an SQL query I have written in MySQL

```
SELECT first_name, last_name
FROM repayment,loan, members
WHERE repayment.loanid = loan.loanid AND repayment.memberid = members.memberid 

WHERE (SUM(amount)+ SUM(lumpsum)) >= loan.amountdue
```

I can't seem to get this to display what I want, a list of folks where the sum of their amount and lumpsum is greater than the amount due.

Kindly help

Comment: 2 `WHERE` in same query?

Comment: and undefined `amount` field too.

Comment: Yes, same query. the amount field is unique only to the repayment table.

Comment: @user2209076 Shivan Raptor says you can't have two `WHERE`s in the same query. Never.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT first_name, last_name
FROM repayment,loan, members
WHERE
 repayment.loanid = loan.loanid AND 
 repayment.memberid = members.memberid 
GROUP BY first_name, last_name
HAVING
 SUM(repayment.repayment_amount) + SUM(repayment.lumpsum) >= SUM(loan.amountdue)
```

Comment: Whoever downvoted, would you explain, what do you think is wrong with my SQL?

Comment: downvote removed, you were putting a `SUM()` in your `WHERE` clause

Comment: +1 but i think it should be `(SUM(amount)+ SUM(lumpsum)) >= SUM(loan.amountdue)` because you are grouping by member not loan

Comment: Oh, yes, as I stated in comment (which I also removed), I saw `SUM()` in statement only after I posted.

Comment: @Stephan I really don't know. Maybe he has only one loan per person, so I left this part unchanged. Only OP can finetune this to his needs.

Comment: i understand but if you put sum it will be safe in both cases :D

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT m.first_name, m.last_name
FROM repayment r,loan l, members m
WHERE r.loanid = l.loanid AND r.memberid = m.memberid 
HAVING (SUM(r.repayment_amount)+ SUM(r.lumpsum)) >= l.amountdue
```

Comment: You will need `GROUP BY` clause